# How to control scroll bar behavior in Cinnamon?

Tags: linux, debian, scrolling, cinnamon

I'm running a Debian 8 machine. I believe its running Cinnamon as the window manager:

```
$ wmctrl -m
Name: Mutter (Muffin)
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A
```

When a mouse click occurs in the scroll bar area, the scrollbar tick snaps to the place of the click rather than paging up/down. I find it to be very annoying behavior.

I cannot find the setting to control the scroll bar behavior. I tired going through the usual suspects, like *General* and *Windows* applets. I also tried searching in the *System Settings* applet, but it returned 0 results.

How do I control the scroll bar behavior in Cinnamon?

---

For completeness, here's the equivalent setting in Mac OS X. Notice the ***Click in the scroll bar*** choices. It can be found in the ***Settings*** app, ***General*** settings.

[image]

Comment: Which programs are you using? Scrollbars aren't drawn or managed by the WM, but by the widget toolkit.

Comment: @grawity - The program is the Terminal. The scroll bars are drawn. Its problematic because I have an unlimited scroll back. Sometimes, I only want to go back 3 pages with 30K lines of scrollback history. Its impossible to use the mouse to move the thumb tick 3 pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The window manager knows *absolutely nothing* about scrollbars. They are drawn by the widget toolkit that each program uses – in GNOME it's mostly GTK+, in KDE it's mostly Qt. Thus scrollbar behavior in GNOME (Cinnamon) programs would be a GTK+ option, and more specifically a GTK 3 option in your case.

To permanently switch back to the old scrollbar behavior, set the [gtk-primary-button-warps-slider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-primary-button-warps-slider) option to `false` in your `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`.

(Yes, it *could* have been added to Cinnamon's "Settings" app, although it's a bit obscure and so more likely to appear in "GNOME Tweak Tool". File a feature request.)

In GTK+ 3, you have alternative methods:

- Click and *hold* the scroll slider for a few seconds, until it switches to "precise mode" (the slider will become thinner), and will only scroll a couple of lines at a time.
- Alternatively, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to immediately enter "precise mode", same as the above.
- Or use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>PageUp</kbd>
  / <kbd>PageDown</kbd> to scroll the terminal page-by-page.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Your knowledge of Linux and Unix is amazing. I going to file a bug report on it. I should not have to edit an INI file by hand for this particular setting.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon

The setting is under "System Settings" > "Themes" > "Settings" tab

Under "Scrollbar Behavior" heading

Disable "Jump to position when clicking in a trough"

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Mint and Cinnamon. [Mck's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1591574/767863) works for me.

Ever easier than adjusting the settings is to simply right-click in the trough, below the slider for page down, or above for page up. This still leaves the default left-click behaviour, which I find useful to go to the top or bottom of a page.